# How is the main StackExchange.com site doing?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm talking about the main site: [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), not any of the specific sites. How is this site doing? Are people using it?

Comment: I never use it. I only ever use the user toplists and the subsites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far so good -- traffic is steadily up. But you *should* use **stackexchange.com**, because it'll let you...

- Search all Stack Exchange sites (and the trilogy)
  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/
- See leaderboards per site and track your position on them
  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/
- Browse questions across multiple sites in a tag set
  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/
- Have new questions in given tag sets [emailed to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72448/tag-sets-on-stackexchange-com-now-support-email-notifications)

And of course it is a [searchable site directory with stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and place to see the [most interesting questions across the entire network](https://stackexchange.com/).

It's good stuff.

Comment: "See leaderboards per site and track your position on them" - The best part.

Comment: Well, this isn't for me, for now at least. I'm getting enough value out of browsing the individual sites, I don't find the need for a central place except area51.